# 3D Coordinates of Point based on 2D Vector on a Plane

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, euclidean-geometry, 3d

I have a plane whose normal $n = (a,b,c)$ is known, also the point $x_0,y_0,z_0$ that the plane passes through is given. Now I am given a 2D vector on this plane $u = (u_1,u_2)$ which is pointing from $x_0,y_0,z_0$ to a new point $X$. $u$ is defined according to the coordinate system which is captured by $v,w$ coordinates, that are projections of real world unit vectors in 3D. How do I find the 3D coordinate of the new point $X$?

[image]

Comment: I think you need to define the vector $u=(u_1,u_2)$ with respect to some axis

Comment: If $u$ is orthogonal to $z$ its coordinates are just $(x_0+u_1,y_0+u_2,z_0)$.

Comment: "... that is, the 2D vector is not based on a seperate coordinate system"
This statement does not make sense. You have given a 2D vector u = (u1, u2). In order to answer your question, we need to know a 3D basis that corresponds to u

Comment: Right - I just realized this as well. Thanks for all the comments.